# How can I update the React Native state if I have an array inside an object and the object is inside in a big array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

I have in state something like this :

```
Array [
  Object {
    "checked": "",
    "currentQuantity": 0,
    "id_in_extras": 206,
    "id_in_extrasCurrent": 0,
    "maxQuantity": 1,
    "minQuantity": 1,
    "selected": Array [],
  },
  Object {
    "checked": "",
    "currentQuantity": 0,
    "id_in_extras": 576,
    "id_in_extrasCurrent": 1,
    "maxQuantity": 1,
    "minQuantity": 1,
    "selected": Array [],
  },
  Object {
    "checked": "",
    "currentQuantity": 0,
    "id_in_extras": 618,
    "id_in_extrasCurrent": 2,
    "maxQuantity": 9,
    "minQuantity": 0,
    "selected": Array [],
  },
]
```

I have some questions.

**1)** There is a more efficient way to update for example the variable *"checked"* in a specified object ? I did like this :

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
extrasCurrent: prevState.extrasCurrent.map(
obj => (obj.id_in_extrasCurrent === index ? Object.assign(obj, { checked:true }) : obj)
)
}));
```

**2)** How I can insert and delete from the array *"selected"* for a specific object in the big array ?

*Thank you !*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly simpler way is to use the spread operator `...` and the current index `i` from `.map()` :

```
const updateIndex = i;
const {myList} = this.state;

this.setState({ myList: myList.map((obj, i) => 
    updateIndex !== i ? obj : { ...obj, checked: true})
});
```

To delete:

```
deleteIndex = i;
const {myList} = this.state;
this.setState({myList: myList.filter((obj, i) => i !== deleteIndex)});
```

To add:

```
const {myList} = this.state;
const newObj = {};
this.setState({
    myList: [...myList, newObj]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to push on the array like this.state.obj.selected.push() then call this.forceUpdate() to re-render component with updated state?

Comment: No , I didn't try but I read that is not a good practice to update the state like this , this.state.something = 1, you need to use this.setState({something:1 }) ...

Comment: you also shouldnt forceUpdate if not needed because its against reacts lifecycle.

Comment: You are right, but you should call forceUpdate or setState({}) to re-render when trying to update state directly like this.state.obj = 'something'. Thoug it is not a good practice.